# JQuery Mobile: How to change data-collapsed with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change data-collapsed of a div (with data-role= "collapsible") with a button.
My div that I tried to change its data-collapsed is:

```
<div id="page01" class="pages" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
```

and the button that i want to change the div's data-collapsed using onclick is:

```
<button onclick="$('#page01').collapsible({ collapsed: false });">Collapse/ Expand</button>
```

I also tried to change my code, but i can't:

```
<button onclick="$('#page01').attrChange('data-collapsed','false')">Collapse/ Expand</button>
```

Or:

```
<button onclick="$('#page01').data('collapsed','false')">Collapse/ Expand</button>
```

Or:

```
<a><button ...>Collapse/ Expand</button></a>
```

Please help me!

Note: I include this on the :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct calls are:

```
$('#page01').collapsible('expand');

$('#page01').collapsible('collapse');
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7k7tvyen/6/)**

See api docs here:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-collapse

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the id right. Your `div` has `id="page03"` but your JS is calling `page01`. Both places need to have the same id.

Comment: thank you. but after change id, my problem don't solved.

Comment: Demo it. Make a JSFiddle, Codepen or whatever